# Reference between two properties in JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to create a class that includes the following properties:

- List
- Count of List

so I thought I could do:

```
class MyList {
    constructor() {
        this._list = [];
        this._listCount = this._list.length;
    }
 }
```

With the method I defined inside, I want to be able to push items into the list and I thought it would automatically increase the _listCount but it stays static. So even though the length of the _list property is 2, the _listCount stays at 0.

Here's the method I created inside my MyList class:

```
add(todo) {
    this._list.push(todo);
}
```

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't automatically increase _listCount when I call the Method on the newly created instance?

Comment: Because `this._listCount` is the value of `this._list.length` when created. JS variables are assigned by value, it's just sometimes the value is a "reference", but in this case it's not. If you want it to be dynamic, use a function.

Answer (score 0):

- Because `Constructor` only call when you create `instance`/`object` of your class.
- When you created object of you class, the `values` assigned to both variables and from here your initial counter is 0.
- You should `increment` your counter from your add `method`

```js
class MyList {
    constructor() {
        this._list = [];
        this._listCount = 0;
    }
    add(todo) {
        this._list.push(todo);
        this._listCount++;
    }    
 }


list = new MyList();
list.add("todo1");
list.add("todo2");

console.log(list)
```

- You can also use `this._list.length` as counter, so you do not need to maintain the counter.

Thanks